# Enviar datos de checkbox a un textarea con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una tabla donde muestro los datos de un usuario y mediante un checkbox quiero enviar el campo email a un textarea, estuve viendo ejemplos y ahora solo lo envío los datos a un alert, quisiera ayuda porfavor.

Código que utilice:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Pregunta 1...</td>
        <td>
            sí <input id="si_1" type="checkbox" class="radio">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pregunta 2...</td>
        <td>
            sí <input id="si_2" type="checkbox" class="radio">
        </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<script>
    document.getElementById("btnEnviar").onclick = function () {
        var radioStatus = new Array();
        var allRadios =
            document.querySelectorAll('input[class="radio"]').forEach(function (el) {

                if (el.checked) {
                    radioStatus.push(el.id);
                }
            })

        var toPost = JSON.stringify(radioStatus);
        alert(toPost);

    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecciona el textarea, y modifica su valor accediendo a la propiedad "value":

```
document.querySelector('textarea').value = toPost
```

El codigo de arriba lo que va a hacer es insertar dentro del textarea, el contenido de la variable "toPost" que al parecer es un array parseado con los IDs de los checkboxes. En tu código no vi ningún "campo email" pero supongo que ya entiendes los próximos pasos a seguir.